# Why didn't Spiro realise that Mulch was lying immediately when he said this?

Tags: artemis-fowl, artemis-fowl-the-eternity-code

When Artemis starts the execution of the plan, Mulch calls Spiro and says this :-

> 'I can hear you Mister Spiro,' said the voice. 'You don't need to do anything. Just talk. The box does the rest.'

Later on, he also mentions that :-

> 'The name is Mo Digence, Mister Spiro. I'm the monkey from Carla Frazetti's team. I don't know what kind of box you have at your end; I just have a plain old telephone.'

Since it is made very clear from the second statement that Mulch does not know what 'box' Spiro is talking about, why didn't Spiro instantly realize that something was amiss and that Mulch was lying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spiro *wanted* Artemis's plan to succeed until the last stage. So even if he did notice Mulch's mess-up, he ignored it to lull Artemis into a false sense of security (that's what he thought anyway).

> Spiro plucked the C Cube from its cushion. “This is fun, Arty. All this tough talk and repartee, but it doesn’t mean anything. I win again, you’ve been outflanked. This has all been a game to me. Amusement. Your little operation has been most educational, if pathetic. But you gotta realize that it’s over now. You’re on your own, and I don’t have time for any more games!”
>
>  
> Artemis sighed, the picture of defeat. “All of this has been a lesson, hasn’t it? Just to show me who’s boss.”
>
> “Exactly. It takes some people a while to learn. I find that the smarter the enemy, the bigger the ego. You had to realize that you were no match for me before you would do what I have asked.” Spiro placed a bony hand on the Irish boy’s shoulder. Artemis could feel the weight of his jewellery. “Now, listen carefully, kid. I want you to unlock this Cube. No more blarney. I never met a computer nerd yet who didn’t leave himself a back door. You open this baby up now, or I’m gonna stop being amused, and believe me you don’t want that.”